# Wi-Fi fails to connect after OS X 10.10.2 Update

Tags: macos, network, wifi, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro 4,1 that was just upgraded to OS X 10.10.2 (14C109).  I've used an [ASUS PCE-AC68](http://www.asus.com/us/Networking/PCEAC68/) wireless adaptor since Mavericks, and haven't had any problems before now.  I understand that this isn't exactly a supported configuration, but the card was plug-and-play since I first purchased it.

Since the OS X 10.10.2 update, the card regularly drops its connection to the router, and rarely is able to reconnect.  Running a command such as `traceroute 192.168.1.1` to try to see if anything is happening between the computer and the router just yields timeout errors, although the System Preferences "Neworking" panel claims that the network is still connected.  Other devices have no problems connecting to the same network from the same location, including a MacBook Pro 10,1 running OS X 10.10.2.

Is there anybody encountering a similar problem or who might be able suggest ways to troubleshoot?  Thanks!

Comment: do you have any more information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Can we see the WiFi connection details from Computer to the Router?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're asking for?  The computer is just doing a standard connection to a WPA2 network, IP provisioned by DHCP.  Everything is essentially on the default automatic settings.

Comment: Sounds pretty basic, but creating an open Guest network and connecting to that has allowed devices future connections to regular passworded network.

Comment: Your RSSI, 802.11?, Transmit rate ? MCS index? ect.. Things like Terminal commands for netstat, ipconfig, ifconfig and other information to determine why is your WiFi dropping.

Comment: Here is one to monitor what is going on "sudo tcpdump -i en0" followed by password will show you who and what.

Comment: I recommend using Apple tools like Wireless Diagnostics, Network Diagnostics or Network Utility (all already on your computer) to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Zo219:  Thanks for the suggestion.  It turns out that having the router produce a public guest network works fine and results in no disconnecting, so the problem appears to be in the WPA2 authentication.

Comment: In fact, WPA2 does not appear to be the culprit, but rather a 5GHz network.  The guest network I had created was 2.4GHz-only, which is why it worked.  When I tried creating a 5GHz public guest network, my computer could not connect, and when I WPA2-protected the 2.4 GHz guest network, the computer _could_ connect (after inputting the password).  Perhaps 10.10.2 introduced something that messed up how 5GHz networks are dealt with.

Comment: Sourcerer, thanks for adding that. It is indeed way glitchier in Yosemite to get on your own 5G network. I should have added,create both network in Airport utility - using some offbeat channels - and once you're on, try switching networks in the network menu extra.

Comment: ... just to add, an app like  WiFi Scanner (accessagility.com) will see your networks (hello, Apple).... connecting that way gets future Yosemite recognition going.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade driver back to version 7.0 from current 7.1 version. Follow the instructions here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6802848

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: This would probably work, but I'm not sure how comfortable I am dropping kernel extensions around.  For now, forcing a 2.4 GHz network seems to be working.  I'll come back to this if I encounter anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some troubleshooting you can do.

1. Open Console and look if any messages there regarding WiFi.
2. Hold "alt" key and click on the WiFi icon:

   2.1. Get Connection information like Radio signal RSSI, the connection mode 802.11?, the Transmit rate and the MCS Index.

   2.2. Scroll down and open Wireless Diagnostics tool

   2.2.1 Open and Run Network Diagnostics.
3. Open Terminal

   3.1 run `lsof -i -P` to see who is using the WiFi connection

   .....

Comment: Wireless Diagnostics occasionally reports, "Your Wi-Fi connection appears to be working as expected", even though I can't actually connect to anything.  Other times, it goes ahead and generates a report, reporting "LAN Connectivity Failure". PHY Mode: 802.11ac; Tx Rate: 7 Mbps; RSSI: -69 dBm; Noise:  -95 dBm.  From `lsof -i -P`, commands include:
UserEvent, SystemUIS, sharingd, GitHub, WiFiAgent, com.apple, Google, BetterTou, Google, Wireless. Network Diagnostics is "unable to diagnose" the source of the problem.

Comment: See above for discussion that WPA2 may be the culprit.